# multiline pattern notation for log in filebeat.yml

Tags: logstash, elastic-stack, filebeat

Could some one help me on defining multi line pattern for below log in filebeat.yml file

```
<entry>
    <severity>FATAL</severity>
    <timestamp>2018-09-18 08:52:23:461 EDT</timestamp>
    <component>framework</component>
    <class>com.mt.xml.CustomerConfigUtil</class>
    <method>loadGlobalProperties</method>
    <arguments></arguments>
    <message>Global Properties re loaded successfully</message>
    <exception></exception>
</entry>

<entry>
    <severity>FATAL</severity>
    <timestamp>2018-09-18 08:52:23:486 EDT</timestamp>
    <component>framework</component>
    <class>com.mt.xml.CustomerConfigUtil</class>
    <method>loadCustomerProperties</method>
    <arguments></arguments>
    <message>Customer Properties re loaded successfully</message>
    <exception></exception>
</entry>
```

when I tried to match starting line

multiline:
    pattern: '^'
    negate: false
    match: after

still each line taking as separate log. Could you please provide right syntax? Thanks!

Comment: I think `pattern: '<entry>' negate: true match: before` should work

Comment: Thanks. But still it didn't work for me

Comment: I think I was mistaken on the `match` param: try with `match: after`.

Comment: Thanks But this also didn't work for me.